# Floating point division in Synthesizable Verilog (Design compiler)

Tags: floating-point, verilog, division

I would like to write a synthesizable module in Verilog that performs a division, and I would like to have a floating point output. I used this code, but I know that both input and output are of the wrong data type. In basic verilog, I know that type real is not synthesizable, therefore I would like to ask you how can I modify my code not to loose accuracy during the division.

```
module div_J_step1(J_step1, step1);
output [11:0] J_step1;
input [11:0] step1;
wire [11:0] J_step1;

localparam [11:0] J =2048;   

always @* begin
J_step1=J/step1;
end

endmodule
```

So my goal is to get an output with some decimals that will go to another block. I will synthesize this block with Synopsys Design Compiler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: there is more than one way to do a division and whatever you do is going to end up using a lot of resource.  Does your system really have no hardware dividers available?  Also are there no constants involved, often you don't really need a divider

Comment: No, I don't have harware dividers already available. It's a custom IC design and I need this digital part to correctly drive my analog part. The only constant is J, while step1 is programmable. I need to make a multiplication with the quotient J_step1 in a following block and I don't want J_step1 to be truncated as an integer, otherwise the result is wrong

Comment: Are you constrained to use a particular floating point format, such as one of the IEEE 754 formats, or can you roll your own, simplified, format? How many digits do you need in the answers? Might integers with a fixed scale factor work?

Comment: No, I'm not costrained to any format. I need 5 decimal digits, for example 2.66666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:
I just shifted left J, so the fractional bits shift left and I can convey the result to the following block as an integer:

```
module div_J_step1(J_step1, step1);
output [16:0] J_step1;
input [11:0] step1;
wire [16:0] J_step1;

localparam [16:0] J =2048<<5;   

always @* begin
J_step1=J/step1;
end

endmodule
```

In the following block, I will shift right >>5 the result, so I will get the correct number. I hope this answer will be helpful. Bye!